# Unordered list navigation with floating left and right elements

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a simple navigation bar at the top of the page with several links – the first is floated to the left using li:first child, the last floated to the right using li:last child, with the remainder centered in the middle of the page.

To all intents and purposes this works – but although the *space* between each of the navigation blocks is the same, the central block is actually positioned much further to the right. I presume this is because the links differ in length – ie 23 characters for link 1, 7 characters for link 2.

Is there any way of resolving this, or should I be using another approach to position the middle block in the absolute centre of the page?

Below is the code that I am currently working with, and a jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pxuVJ/

**EDIT 19:28 13.05.12**
As it is a little confusing to explain, I've taken a screengrab which illustrates the problem: http://bit.ly/Khd8cN

Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<nav>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">title of site</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link 1">link 1</a></li>
    <li>&#8226;</li>
    <li><a href="#link2">link 2</a></li>
    <li>&#8226;</li>
    <li><a href="#link 3">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
font: 10pt Courier;
position: fixed;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
height: 20px;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 10;
text-align: center;
}

nav li { display: inline; list-style: none; }
nav li:first-child { float: left; }
nav li:last-child { float: right; }​
```

Comment: no sure what you mean, What I see is, TITLE OF SITE to the left, LINK 1 - LINK2 - LINK3 at the middle and CONTACT to the right. Even If I change LINK 1 for a larger text (27 chars) still the 3 middle links are in the middle...

Comment: Sorry – it's a little confusing to explain. They group of three is in the middle of the page relative to the other links, but not to the middle of the page. Perhaps this screengrab will help: http://bit.ly/Khd8cN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shreedhar is quite right in that using 'float' is not required – although rather than guessing the margins assigning *li:first-child* and *li:last child* absolute positions seems to be a better method – it also seems to work with any number of links in the central block.

```
nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    text-align:left;
}

nav li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
dispaly:inline;
```

you can use

```
nav li { float:left; list-style: none; padding : 10px; }
nav li:first-child { margin-right:50px; } nav li:last-child { margin-left:50px; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really achieving the result I'm after – the three links should be centered on the page, with 'title' on the far left and 'contact' on the far right. I've taken a screengrab which might help further: http://bit.ly/Khd8cN

Comment: try this : 

  nav li:first-child { margin-right:50px; }

  nav li:last-child { margin-left:50px; }​

don't give float:left and float : right for first and last li's.

Comment: Ah – you've pointed me in the right direction, thank you. When you say "don't give float:left and float:right for first and last li's, is that because it's bad practice, or because it isn't applicable for your suggested answer?

Comment: its not gud practice. and also mark my answer as accepted, if my answer was useful for you. :)