# Floating part of Unordered List Left and part of it Right on the Same Line

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573793/unordered-list-navigation-with-floating-left-and-right-elements) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471662/how-to-make-the-float-left-and-float-right-on-the-same-line) but I haven't been able to apply their solutions to my specific problem.

I have an unordered list like so:

http://tinker.io/926d2/5

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    /ul>
</nav>
```

But the last child has to be floated left and the other elements floated right.

One note, I want to avoid adding classes or html around any of the list elements as they are being generated by PHP in one variable. However, adding classes to the nav and ul tags is fine.

What I have come up with so far is the following css:

```
nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
}

nav li:last-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

However, the first four elements are "blocking" the last child from being able to align to the left.

I have tried floating, and positioning the first four elements absolutey, and can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Am I missing something? Just change the `text-align: left` to `float: left` i.e. `nav li:last-child { float: left;}`. Works fine in the demo: http://tinker.io/926d2/7

Comment: This? http://tinker.io/926d2/8

Comment: Both would be perfect if the a, b, c and d would be all the way on the right side of the page.

Comment: Kind of like this: http://tinker.io/926d2/9 except without the reversed order of the a, b, c and d elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/T5xc9/ see this fiddle. It uses `text-align` and `float` to achieve what you desire and doesn't use position absolute. Everything is `relative`

Answer (score 2):

Can this help? I used no classes, only positioning.
http://tinker.io/926d2/16

Comment: Wow! You sir have done what I was beginning to think was an impossible task!

Comment: I am sorry but Ejay perhaps has a better solution that does not use absolute positioning. I do very much appreciate you answer nonetheless!